# Optimization and objective function using Scipy

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I am trying to optimize an objective function using scipy. I simplified what I would like to do to focus on the problem more. There is an array called `operating`, which is an independent variable to optimize the output( indeed it is the array makes the objective function optimized). `operating` could be **0** , **1**, or **0.5**, and each of these values can affect another variable called `TI`, so `TI = f(operating)` , and this `TI` also changes the objective function.

```
objective = function - penalty 
penalty= f(TI)
```

So **changing** the `operating` leads to **changing** the `TI` and, consequently, the `objective` function.
I have also used the following lines to optimize using scipy :

```
x0 = np.full((wt),0.6)
bounds=np.full((wt,2),(0,1)).reshape(-1, 2)             
res= minimize(wt_simulation, x0=x0, bounds=bounds,method='powell',options={'maxiter': 1e4, 'disp': True})
```

The problem is that `x0` (=operating) must be a mix of **0.5,1** and **0** in the defined range to consider all three values in operating, and then these values will be changed in each optimization to get the best deal for the objective. I tried different methods, and I think the only option to use in such optimization is the `Powell` method, but the fact is that the final result is incorrect, and I got the wrong values. So I think there is a mistake by me in the optimization's options or something like this. If I have only two values in operating, optimization works correctly. so how can solve his problem to optimize the function by considering those three values in operation?
for instance, even in `x0` I change 0,6 to another value again I could get different results, so which value should be correct?

```
x0 = np.full((wt),0.6)
```

Comment: You have asked more than enough questions to know that it's always recommended to provide a [minimal **reproducible** example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). That being said, it's not really clear what you mean by *mixed value*.

Comment: @joni, i have changed a little bit the question to make the problem much clear.

Comment: It's still not a reproducible example.

Comment: @joni but I cannot understand what is the problem of the question? would you please mention it so that I can solve the problem